# Manga where the main character gets the ability to switch jobs and his female friend/classmate gets the saintess job

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am searching for a manga I read a while ago. In the story, the male main character (MC) gets the ability to switch jobs, like ninja, woodworker and many more. I don't remember if its an isekai, but I don't think so. Here is some of the story and little details:

The whole class goes through an awakening ceremony and his female friend/classmate gets the saintess job/class and she heals him first. The teacher is angry because many people would pay to be healed first by a saintess. He is seen as weak.

The class goes through many challenges, like they need to build a house. All his classmates struggle while he just switches his job and builds an indestructible wood cabin. Later, some of his classmates try to burn it, but it won't burn.

Another challenge was to find a hidden wyvern-skin. It was hidden as a flag. While the teacher was still talking about it, he walks in with it. Later, in class, he makes a legendary coat out of it and the teacher plays it off and says the tools he used were legendary. That lie bites him in the ass later.

The MC also finds a rare and super-delicious mushroom and eats it. The teacher find out and tries to get him to sell it, but he already ate it. His female classmate also is in love with him and shares food with him.

I think the last thing I read was when he was attacked by a female ninja in his house. His classmates don't know about his abilities.

I think if you need more info, you can ask, and I can try to remember more. Thanks.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It was ***[Exiled in a Class Trial for Poor Dexterity](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kiyoubinbou-jou-wo-tateru-kaitaku-gakuen-no-rettousei-na-no-ni-joukyuu-shoku-no-skill-to-mahou-ga-subete-tsukaemasu-comic)***.

> The boy Leopin was born with unnaturally high dexterity. From an early age, he used his dexterity to contribute to his peers in a variety of crafts. Leopin and his friends entered the Royal Pioneer Academy. However, during the “Ritual of Ability Development” at the entrance ceremony, the status given to Leopin was disastrous. “Occupation: Unemployed.” “All statuses except dexterity remain at their initial values and do not grow.” “Skill is dextrous master of none.” Leopin’s classmates exiled him because he had nothing to offer other than his dexterity. Leopin is placed in the “Special Training Class”, a class for failures. Leopin is left all alone. However, he realizes that the skill he has been given, “Poor Dexterity,” has an unexpected performance. That is…You can convert your dexterity status to any other status. You can change your occupation to any one you want.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept by clicking on the checkmark in 42 hours.